# AngularJS - Decode Byte Array and Play Audio File (Wav/MP3)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-audio-api

Using below service to play audio file (wav/mp3) that comes in byte array format.

```
myAudioService.getAudioTone(userid).then(function (data) {

        var context;    // Audio context
        var buf;        // Audio buffer
        $window.AudioContext = $window.webkitAudioContext;
        context = new AudioContext();

        $timeout(function () {

        $scope.playByteArray = function(){

            var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
            var bufferView = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              bufferView[i] = data[i];
            }

            context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function(buffer) {
                buf = buffer;
                play();
            });
        }

        $scope.play = function(audioBuffer){

            // Create a source node from the buffer
            var source = context.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = buf;
            // Connect to the final output node (the speakers)
            source.connect(context.destination);
            // Play immediately
            source.start(0);

        }    


        if(data.length !== '' || data !== ''){
            $scope.playByteArray();
        }
        }, 3000);

});
```

The functions are called but it throws below exception.

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data`

How do I run it in Chrome, FF and IE ?

P.S. `$window` and `$timeout` are already defined in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message `arrayBuffer` doesn't contain what you think it contains.  You should verify that the bytes in the array are the same as the encoded wav/mp3 file.

Comment: Is there a way to verify that the bytes in the array are the same as the encoded wav/mp3 file ?

Comment: Don't know since you don't show where data comes from.  But you could verify that the mp3/wav file can be decoded by using something like `fetch(url).then(response => { context.decodeAudioData(response); })`